geckodriver connection refused in Amazon Linux
I am trying to get my Selenium tests running on Amazon Linux, but keep getting this error

Selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: **Connection refused (os error 111).

The Python script works fine on my local machine (macOS).
Versions

selenium 4.18.1
firefox 93.0
geckodriver 0.31.0

Code
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # headless setting
service = Service(log_output='geckodriver.log')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)

Here are the output logs of the geckodriver:
1714835716700   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:46439
1714835716713   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "42889" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileizqbCI"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
1714835717676   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled

I am sure that the versions of Firefox and GeckoDriver are compatible, as indicated in the documentation: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html.

You're getting a connection refused.  That means that the web server you're trying to use basically said "no, I won't talk to you".  It's possible that the server blocks connections from AWS, especially since it will "talk" to you from your local machine.
